# OpenCV: Video I/O

Tags: opencv, video-capture, camera-calibration

Can someone explain to me the `CV_CAP_PROP_FOCUS` property in OpenCV? I have a auto focus camera and I want to fix the focus manually. Since `OpenCV` 2.4 does not have `CV_CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS` property, I'm trying to do this in another way.